# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in factory function

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def maker(n):
  def action(x):
   return x*n
   return action

f=maker(2)
print f(3)
```

I have problem here with type error.How to solve this two arguments problem,one is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `return action` out of `action` function :

```
def maker(n):
  def action(x):
   return x*n
  return action

f=maker(2)
print f(3)
```

Result:

```
6
```

*Note* that in factory function you must return the inner function as the result of main function.

Comment: Ok,works now.But what about f=maker(2),can I put it inside the action or  it does not matter?

Comment: @RichardRublev No you can not do such thing! Its very simple : when you didn't create the function you can not call it!